# Initializing series object using numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

As i was starting with pandas and tried to understand how to create series using given array or list, i came across this line...

***If you initialize a series object with the help of NumPy then you can hold only homogeneous data within it.***

I am not able to understand what it says! I guess series can hold any dtype as long as it is same throughout that particular vector, isn't it? Then what does the above line mean in this context?

here is the code written just before this statement......

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

labels = ['a','b','c']
my_data = [10,20,30]
arr = np.array(my_data)

print(pd.Series(my_data))
print('==================')
print(pd.Series(my_data,index=labels))
```

Comment: It means if you mix strings and numeric values they will get converted by pandas to strings since each series/column can only hold 1 dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have in *my_data* **non-homogenous** items, e.g. a mixture of numbers
and strings, e.g.:

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
my_data = [10, 20, 30, 'xx', 12.55]
arr = np.array(my_data)
s = pd.Series(my_data, index=labels)
```

and print *arr*, you will get:

```
array(['10', '20', '30', 'xx', '12.55'], dtype='<U11')
```

Note that each item in *arr* is a **string**.

At the first glance, the same holds for *s*. When you print it, you will get:

```
a       10
b       20
c       30
d       xx
e    12.55
dtype: object
```

When you look at the items itself, it is not obvious what is their type, but look
at the bottom line: `dtype: object`.
The first thought is "actually a string", but as a matter of fact it means
"it depends from particular cell".

To confirm it, take a look at individual cells:

`type(s['a'])` yields *int*, `type(s['d'])` yields *str* and
`type(s['e'])` yields *float* (each of them are descendants of *object*).

And now try the **homogenous** variant:

```
my_data = [10, 20, 30, 4.12, 12.55]
```

(either *int* or *float*, other "initial" instructions like above).

Now when you print *arr*, you will get:

```
array([10.  , 20.  , 30.  ,  4.12, 12.55])
```

so all elements are coerced to *closest possible ancestor*, in this
case just *float*.

When you print *s*, the result is:

```
a    10.00
b    20.00
c    30.00
d     4.12
e    12.55
dtype: float64
```

so its type is inherited from *arr*.

This time, when you print *type(s['a'])* (or whathever other cell),
you will get *float*.

Note also such a difference between plain *pythonic* list and a *Numpy* array:

- in a *list* each element has its own type,
- in a *Numpy* array the type is assigned to the **array**, i.e.
  all its elements have the same type (although they can be **subtypes**
  of the "basic" type for the whole array).

So when you create a *Series* or *DataFrame* from *Numpy* array (1-D or 2-D
respectively):

- *Series* object inherits type from the source array,
- each column of a *DataFrame* also inherit type from this array.

Of course, you can create a DataFrame also from a number of separate 1-D
*Numpy* arrays (sources for columns), each with its own type and the
resulting DataFrame also will inherit source types, **separately**
for each column, from respective *Numpy* arrays.

## Edit following the question

Only as late as in version *1.0* of *Pandas* there were introduced some
new, experimental dtypes, among them **string** (just what you ask for).

Apparently *Pandas* authors recognized that there is a need for an "explicit"
string, not "any object, maybe a string".

But these changes are introduced stepwise, for now not including existing
methods to read content from files.
E.g. *read_csv* operates "the old way", i.e. if some column is of
non-numerical and non-datelike type, then *object* type is assumed.

To allow conversion of such columns to "new" dtypes, *convert_dtypes()*
method has been added, to be called e.g. after *read_csv*, in an attempt
to change the type of each column to some of "new" dtypes (if possible).

To get more complete image of what was recenty added, and how to use it,
read the *Pandas* documentation about new dtypes, *NA* scalar and
working with missing data.

Comment: i have got some part of it, thanks for your vivid explanation! however in both cases, if we are initializing series object with numpy, then why in the first case it says dtype is an object and in the second dtype as a float? shouldn't it say that even in case of non homogenous data, the dtype should be clearly string since we initialized the series object from numpy? if i am anywhere wrong , do let me know plz.....

Answer (score 1):

```
In [550]: labels = ['a','b','c'] 
     ...: my_data = [10,20,30] 
     ...: arr = np.array(my_data)                                                        
In [551]: arr                                                                            
Out[551]: array([10, 20, 30])   # array with `int` dtype

In [553]: pd.Series(my_data)                                                             
Out[553]: 
0    10
1    20
2    30
dtype: int64
In [554]: pd.Series(my_data, index=labels)                                               
Out[554]: 
a    10
b    20
c    30
dtype: int64
```

Note the `dtype`.

A list with mix of int and strings:

```
In [555]: alist = [10,'twenty',30]                                                       
In [556]: pd.Series(alist, index=labels)                                                 
Out[556]: 
a        10
b    twenty
c        30
dtype: object
```

note change in dtype

Make array from that list - note the string dtype:

```
In [557]: np.array(alist)                                                                
Out[557]: array(['10', 'twenty', '30'], dtype='<U21')
In [558]: pd.Series(np.array(alist), index=labels)                                       
Out[558]: 
a        10
b    twenty
c        30
dtype: object
In [559]: _.to_numpy()                                                                   
Out[559]: array(['10', 'twenty', '30'], dtype=object)
```

[558] looks the same as [556], but the `10,20` are different - ints in one, strings in the other.  For good or bad, pandas displays strings and numbers the same.

Comment: thnx i will try to get that in